# Reasons for having fonts.gstatic.com in the csp-report - without having the external URL inside the HTML/JS?

Tags: content-security-policy

I implemented a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) and use the `report-uri` parameter to track violations of the policy.

While tracking the violations I have noticed such entries:

```
"csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "https://www.example.com/",
    "referrer": "",
    "violated-directive": "font-src",
    "effective-directive": "font-src",
    "disposition": "enforce",
    "blocked-uri": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/mulish/v12/1Ptvg83HX_SGhgqk0AotcqA.woff2",
    "status-code": 200,
    "script-sample": ""
}
```

The strange thing is that neither in the HTML, nor the Javascript files, nor in the CSS files I am using any external font. They are all clean from external URLs.

As you can see the `script-sample` is also empty.

I assume that it could be a browser extension of the user that injects the font into the website, which then gets blocked by CSP.

What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

I found this nice collection of CSP violations: https://github.com/nico3333fr/CSP-useful/blob/master/csp-wtf/explained.md

One seems to be similar to the one I discovered.

```
"blocked-uri": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxko2lTMeWA_kmIyWrkNCwPc.woff2",
```

> Might be related to extension that allow to personalize fonts, like [Font Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-changer/obgkjikcnonokgaiablbenkgjcdbknna)

This is better than nothing.

If someone else discovers another source of the violation, please post it here.